# How to cache an image and use it later in EaselJS?

Tags: css-sprites, sprite, easeljs, sprite-sheet

I have a very basic sprite animation. How to cache an image  and use it in the "images" part of the sprite sheet creation?
I tried with:

```
Image1= new Image(2779,1135)
Image1.src = "img/contur.png"
```

but I don't knwo how to include Image 1 in the "images" section.

stage = new createjs.Stage(document.getElementById("testCanvas"));
    stage.clear();

```
var ss = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
    "animations": {"run": [0, 50]},
    "images": ["img/contur.png"],
    "frames":
        {
        "height": 140,
        "width": 231,
        "regX": 0,
        "regY": 0,
        "count": 51
        }
    });

var grant = new createjs.Sprite(ss, "run");

stage.addChild(grant);
createjs.Ticker.setFPS(24);
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question, you want to load the image prior to its usage in the spritesheet.

You have 2 ways to do this:

1. Add a callback on `img.load`:

   ```
   img = new Image();
   img.src = "img/contur.png";
   img.onload = function(event) {
       // you can create spritesheet here
   }
   ```
2. Using PreloadJS (recommended):

   ```
   loader   = new createjs.LoadQueue(true);
   loader.on('complete', function(event) {
       // you can create spritesheet here
   });
   loader.loadManifest([{id:'imageX', src:'img/contur.png'}]);
   ```

   if that is the case, you also need to run a web server (for example, using python: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8088`)

For both options, you just need to use the path to image (the browser will get the preloaded image automagically):

```
var ss = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
    "animations": {"run": [0, 50]},
    "images": ["img/contur.png"],
    "frames": {
        "height": 140,
        "width": 231,
        "regX": 0,
        "regY": 0,
        "count": 51
    }
});
```

If you are using PreloadJS, you can specify the loaded image object by an alias (defined on manifest):

```
"images": [loader.getResult('imageX')],
...
```

**NOTE: remember to call `stage.update()` after adding stuff to the stage or to animate the frames, otherwise it will simply show an empty canvas or a static image.**

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. Indeed, the image gets loaded (when I start the game) but it still stays a few second before displaying on the canvas (after the user finished the lvl). On the second finished lvl it shows up instantly. Is there need for another cache inside EaselJS?

Comment: I have a bigger spritesheed to work on bigger screens too. How can I scale the spritesheet down to fit the canvas area?